# Scaling limit of a discrete analogue of the heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

For $f \in L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$, given $\varepsilon > 0$, define the function $T_\varepsilon f$ on $\mathbb R^d$ by

$$T_\varepsilon f(x) := \frac{1}{|B_\varepsilon (x)|} \int_{B_\varepsilon (x)} f(y) \,  dy$$

Using $T^n_\varepsilon$ to denote the $n$-fold composition of $T_\varepsilon$, define the function $u_\varepsilon: \mathbb R^n \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ by

$$u_\varepsilon (x, t) = T^{[t/\varepsilon]}_\varepsilon f(x),$$

where $[\cdot]$ denotes the floor function, and by convention we set $T^0_\varepsilon f = f$.

**Question:** Is it true that $u_\varepsilon$ converges in supremum norm to some limit $u$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$? If so, can we characterise $u$ as the solution to some PDE?

**Comments:**

I initially guessed it would converge to the solution of the heat equation, but this cannot be the case as the $u_\varepsilon$ have finite propagation speed uniformly bounded in $\varepsilon$. It seems to resemble a heat equation but with finite propagation speed.

Comment: Well, $u_\epsilon$ converges to zero uniformly on $\mathbb R^n \times [a, \infty)$ for every $a > 0$. However, $v_\epsilon(x,t) = u_\epsilon(x,\epsilon^{1/2}t)$ seems to converge to the solution of the heat equation (uniformly if $f$ is uniformly continuous). A simple proof can be given using [Donsker's invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: by simple proof you mean one of the first claim that things converge to zero uniformly, right?

Comment: @WillieWong: Oh, I messed up the exponents. What I meant is that if $X_n$ is the random walk with increments distributed uniformly over the unit ball, then $T_\epsilon^n f(x) = \mathbb E f(\epsilon X_n)$, and so $u(x, t/\epsilon) = T_\epsilon^{[t/\epsilon^2]} f(x) = \mathbb E f(\epsilon X_{[t/\epsilon^2]})$ converges to the solution of the heat equation. So it turns out that $u_\epsilon(x, t)$ converges to $f(x)$ (uniformly if $f$ is uniformly continuous). Sorry!

Comment: Ah yes, I was wondering if a different scaling would be the correct one, since it would fix the finite propagation speed issue. I will try to work out the details using Donsker’s theorem as you suggest.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Oh, I see you already provided them. Yes that makes sense, very nice!

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! @MateuszKwaśnicki